# Collapse all kendoGridDetailTemplates on filter click in KendoUI grid in angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is my function to collapse detail grid on click.  The same function will call on filter click to check if any detail grid is open or not. If open then it should hide detail grid. This function works properly on click but not when collapsed by clicking the minus button.  It's not working when filter button is applied from another component.

**IN GRIDVIEW.COMPONENT.TS**

```
public OnMasterRowCollapse(dataItem: any): any {
        //if (dataItem.index != null) {
            let firstColumn: HTMLElement = null;
            firstColumn = this.GetFirstColumnOfMasterRow(dataItem.index);
            firstColumn.classList.remove('border_left_blue');
}
private GetFirstColumnOfMasterRow(rowIndex: number): any {
        let gridMasterRows: any = null;
        let gridMasterRowFirstColumn: HTMLElement = null;

        gridMasterRows = document.getElementsByClassName('k-master-row gridRow');

        if (gridMasterRows != null && gridMasterRows.length > 0) {
            gridMasterRowFirstColumn = (<HTMLElement>gridMasterRows[rowIndex].firstElementChild);
        }

        return gridMasterRowFirstColumn;
    }
```

**IN dashboard.component.ts**

```
public onQAFilterClicked(): void {
        //this.advanceSearchDataContext = {};
        if (this.qaClicked) {
            this.advanceSearchDataContext.Status = "QA";
            this.qaClicked = false;
            this.kcClicked = true;
            this.putawayClicked = true;
        }
        else {
            this.advanceSearchDataContext.Status = "";
            this.qaClicked = true;
        }
        this.GetDataSource();

        let row = this.dataSource;
        var rowlist = {};
        if (row && row.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                rowlist['dataItem'] = row[i];
                rowlist['index'] = i;

                if (rowlist) {
                  //this will call a function in gridview.component.ts
                    this.gridViewComponent.OnMasterRowCollapse(rowlist);
                }
            }
        }

        console.log("clicked");
        console.log(this.advanceSearchDataContext);
}
```

I am providing the same input in dataItem in OnMasterRowCollapse in gridview.component.ts for both calls. Same things happens on both calls. But the detail grid is not closing when filter applied.

I can't figure it out what is wrong with this code.